# Save iPhone backup offline

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

Is it possible to download an iCloud backup of my iPhone to save offline? I want to achieve this without the use of iTunes syncing.

EDIT: I would like to download the backup onto my Mac and then perhaps save it on Google Drive. Let me describe my use case. My iPhone 5 does not have a lot of disk space. I used to use Garage Band on it, but I don't any more, and I'd like to delete it from my phone without losing its data, in case I want to access the music I made someday in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :)  Where do you wish to download the backup, iOS device or Mac/PC? What do you wish to do with the backup "without the use of iTunes syncing"? Please edit the question to add the details.

Comment: When I do a backup of my phone with iTunes - it is always local...

Comment: @NimeshNeema I extended the description

Answer (score 1):

A couple years ago I used a paid software called iPhone Backup Extractor, to download a copy of your backups or other iCloud synced data. iTunes was not required in any of the steps. I have not used it in a while, so I am not sure if it will still work as it did, but you could give it a try.